# Is there a function $g(X,Y)$ such that $E[g(X,Y)|X,Z]$ is constant in $X$?

Tags: conditional-expectation

More precisely, consider three random variables $X,Y,Z$, with $f(Y|X,Z)$ being the density of $Y$ conditional on $X,Z$. Say that this density is "regular" enough (e.g., continuous in all three variables). Is it true that, for each such density function $f(Y|X,Z)$, we can find a function $g(X,Y)\neq 0$ such that:

$E[g(X,Y)|X,Z]$ is constant in X?

If this is not true, are there well known sufficient conditions for this to be true?

Comment: I suspect you haven't stated the question you actually have, because it is trivial that any $g$ of the form $g(X,Y)=h(Y)$ where $E[h(Y)]$ exists and is finite will work.  Maybe by "constant in $X$" you mean something other than *doesn't vary with $X$?*

Comment: The point here is that if Y is not independent of X,Z, I can't pick up any h(Y) as you suggested. The question is: for any given f(Y|X,Z) (including distributions where Y is not independent of X,Z), is there a function g(X,Y) such that [(,)|,] is constant in X? 

By constant in X, I do mean that the expectation doesn't vary with X.

Comment: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have finite expectations.  Consider $g(X,Y)=E[X]Y-XE[Y\mid X].$

Comment: Consider even that the above is differentiable with respect to X. In your example:

$E[E[X]Y-XE[Y|X]|X,Z]=E[X]E[Y|X,Z]-XE[Y|X]$

Taking derivatives with respect to X, we get:

$E[X]{\partial E[Y|X,Z]\over \partial X}-E[Y|X]-{\partial E[Y|X]\over \partial X} X$

There must be distributions f(Y|X,Z) such that the above is not constant in X.

Comment: Trying to be more precise about the question:  is it true that for any given distribution $f(Y|X,Z)$, we can pick up a function $g(X,Y; f)$ such that $E[g(X,Y;f)|X,Z]$ is constant in X?

Or is there an interesting/non-trivial class of such distributions?